# is there a blogging cms like wordpress built in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, blogs

I've been looking at creating themes for wordpress, but I'm not a fan of PHP. I'd rather use Rails.

Does anyone know of a blogging engine written using Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://radiantcms.org/
http://www.enkiblog.com/
https://github.com/fdv/typo/wiki/

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of blog engines written using rails. Kalyan M highlighted a few good ones. Here are a couple more for you to consider based upon your needs:

1. Refinery CMS

   - I tested this cms before and really like how simple it is to use. In fact, RailsCast did a really nice video on how to install and use this. http://railscasts.com/episodes/332-refinery-cms-basics
2. Browser CMS

   - I have not used this before but my fellow non-dev friend who used it really like that it is non-dev friendly.
3. Locomotive CMS
4. Radiant CMS

   - This is one of the oldest Rails cms out there. It has a large amount of extensions contributed by the community and is constantly improving. I would recommend that you test this out.

Good luck!

Comment: some of these are paid. It would have been nice that this is stated